# RTK Query - How to reset pagination when args changed

Tags: reactjs, caching, redux-toolkit, infinite-scroll

I have a issue when implementing a "load on demand" strategy (that keep previous result according to filters / sorting criteria) with createAPI & I am not against some help :wink:

The createAPI implementation : https://github.com/jy95/jy95.github.io/blob/nextjs/src/redux/services/gamesAPI.tsx

The [component that uses it](https://github.com/jy95/jy95.github.io/blob/nextjs/src/app/%5Blocale%5D/games/_client/GamesGalleryGrid.tsx) doesn't seem to update page properly when either

```
// Active filters
const activeFilters = useAppSelector(
    (state) => state.games.activeFilters
);

// Active sorters
const activeSorters = useAppSelector(
    (state) => state.games.sorters
);
```

changed. Any ideas on how to fix it ?

You can see that behavior on https://jy95-github-izr1c6y8j-jy95.vercel.app/en/games when :

1. Wait for initial load
   2 Click on "Load More"
2. Apply a filter (for example the platform one with GBA)
3. Page used the old value (2) whereas it should be 0

Thanks in advance